# Is this wall on the second floor a load bearing wall?

Tags: load-bearing

I am removing a small shower in my master bathroom in order to install a larger one.

I want to know if this wall is load bearing, I don't think so but i want to make sure.

There is no wall underneath it on the first floor.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWlzp.jpg[image]

Comment: It looks to me like there is a ridge beam for the roof support and not trusses.If that is the case then that wall should not be weight bearing.

Answer (score 2):

1. There's no wall directly below this one.
2. Only 2 of the 3 (visible) studs in this wall are full height.
3. This wall is 3 feet (max?) long and would only bear the weight of 2 or 3 rafters on one side of the ridge.

If this wall is bearing any load, it's because the studs were cut a fraction too long and were forced into place, slightly lifting the rafters above and, therefore taking some of their weight. It wasn't designed to do this and wasn't designed to be load bearing.

**Note**: I am not a structural engineer, so I cannot guarantee this answer 100%. Any failure or damage to your residence is the result of you taking advice from random strangers on the internet. However, I would pull it down in my own house without concern.